# Accessing the `UniqueId` passed to a JUnit5 Session from inside an Extension

Tags: junit5, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test, junit5-extension-model

Background:

https://github.com/sageserpent-open/americium/issues/69

https://github.com/sageserpent-open/americium/issues/66

These concern an extension that generates test data for a JUnit5 test, analogous to `@ParameterizedTest`. When running a test from an IDE such as IntelliJ, clicking on a specific test case results in a `UniqueId` specific to that test case being sent to JUnit5 via its `Launcher` API, wrapped up in a `LauncherDiscoveryRequest`.

This finds its way down to some filtering logic in [TestTemplateTestDescriptor](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/a0511cca0a5566a7af96bf6d20e402f3a41b9900/junit-jupiter-engine/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine/descriptor/TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java#L133). The filter checks the `UniqueId` for each potential test case against the one passed to the `Launcher`, so only those test cases (usually just one of them) is run.

So far, so good.

Problem:

The problem I have is that instead of ploughing through all the test cases (because 1. this can take a long time and 2. sometimes the test cases are produced in a non-deterministic fashion that depends on the outcome of whether the previous test cases passed or failed), I want the extension to use the `UniqueId` passed via `Launcher` to directly generate the corresponding test case only. This would still be passed through the aforementioned filtration, but the extension needs to get upfront access to that `UniqueId`.

What I tried:

There is a callback `TestExecutionListener.dynamicTestRegistered` that seems to do the right thing, only investigation shows that it is called just prior to each test case being run, downstream of the filtration and the generation of the test cases. I need this to happen upfront, specifically in  the implementation of `TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider.provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts`.

That method is passed a `ExtensionContext` with a `UniqueId` property, but it refers to the entire test class and not the one I'm after that identifies the specific test case.

Tantalisingly, the actual implementation passed in is a `TestTemplateExtensionContext` and that does contain a `TestTemplateTestDescriptor` that in turn contains a filter with the desired `UniqueId` in there, but none of that is accessible without reflection and a lot of unsafe assumptions.

What I want:

Is there a clean way of getting that top-level `UniqueId` passed to the `Launcher` from my extension?

Comment: Idea: Register a `TestExecutionListener` and implement `testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan)`. Iterating through the testPlan will give you all identified test descriptors and thereby the unique ID.

Comment: Thanks @johanneslink, I tried this, but the unique ids in the `TestPlan` aren't quite exact - the descendant ones only go down as far as the method level, not right down to the test cases. Ironically, the `InternalTestPlan` does have this level of detail, but I found this witty comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/e56eb7d99eeed0d58c1c497706680513c68ec73e/junit-platform-launcher/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java#L83 :-)

Comment: Update: found out about `LauncherDiscoveryListener` and the earlier `LauncherSessionListener`. I'm hoping that the former (either via service-loading or registered via the latter) will give me access to the desired `LauncherDiscoveryRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, this grants access to the unique id(s) for the replayed test case(s) in the `LauncherDiscoveryRequest` without breaking abstractions:

```
public class LauncherDiscoveryListenerOpenSesame
        implements LauncherDiscoveryListener {
    @Override
    public void launcherDiscoveryStarted(LauncherDiscoveryRequest request) {
        final List<UniqueId> uniqueIds = request
                .getSelectorsByType(UniqueIdSelector.class)
                .stream()
                .map(UniqueIdSelector::getUniqueId)
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(uniqueIds);

        LauncherDiscoveryListener.super.launcherDiscoveryStarted(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Test running has two phases: discover and execute. Discovery might be too early for your purpose, then TestExecutionListener is the better choice.